# how to get data from mongodb find by id and store in local

Tags: node.js

how to get data from mongodb by ID and store in local variable i am new in nodejs please help me

```
export function upsert(req, res) {

var getjob =  Job.findById(req.params.id)

console.log(getjob);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get it in the callback

```
var getjob = null;

Job.findById(req.params.id, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('job', response);
    getjob = response;
  }
});
```

Of course Job is from your DB object ?

```
var Job = mongoClient.collection('job');
```

Comment: req.params.id is different from null ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
 Job.findById(req.body.id, function (err, getjob) {
  console.log(getJob); 
})
```